# android comparing dates I couldn't compare two dates...I referred many tutorials

Tags: android, date, android-datepicker

I am using the datepicker dialog and am trying to compare the  current date  with the date specified in the dialog.
if the date is before the current date I wish to display invalid date.

Both current date and date entered are in same format. but I am getting error. when printing in console both current date and entered date are coming the the same format

```
if(date1.before(currDate))
{
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the valid Date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

result:

> current date 5/7/2017
>
> picked date 5-7-2017

Comment: share complete code

Comment: parse string date to  java Date after that perform operation

Comment: Please add your Error Log as well as add the code where you have applied your logic.

Comment: how to parse date

Comment: current date    String currDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);                     then using date picker i got the users date     and am trying to compare the dates    if(date1.before(currDate))
           {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the valid Date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
Date date= formatter.parse(strDate);

Comment: @akhilesh0707 thank u....i have done this  Date date;
            d1 = formatter.parse(date1);
            d2 = formatter.parse(currDate);

am getting   error as date unknown class...d1,d2 in ed lines

Comment: You can try by splitting the String and then compare it.

Comment: can you post your other code

Comment: share your code what have you implemented

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        String strCurrDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String strAnotherDate = "05/03/2017";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        try {
            Date currDate = formatter.parse(strCurrDate);
            Date anotherDate = formatter.parse(strAnotherDate);
            if (currDate.before(anotherDate)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the valid Date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: how to convert string to date

Comment: converting string to Date you need to use SimpleDateFormat parse  method

Comment: @shwettha try url for string to date format https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-to-date

Answer (score 0):

you can directly deactivate past dates in datepicker by

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

You can compare time only by converting it in milliseconds

```
  Date setDateTime = input.parse(todayTime);
  calendar1.setTime(setDateTime);
  selectedTime=calendar1.getTimeInMillis();

  msTime = System.currentTimeMillis();//current time
//and compare msTime and setsetDateTime 
  if (selectedTime>msTime){
//your logic
}
```

or you can direct compare date by formating date format in digits only like 
for 5-7-2017 is 572017 and compare it to selected date in same format

Comment: thank u..am not compring time..can u ppl say how to convert string to date

Comment: or u can make date picker to deactivate past dates 
                                      
        bydatePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code for date comparison

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public static boolean compareSameDate(String firstDate, String secondDate) {
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd/MM/yyyy",
            Locale.ENGLISH);

        Date date1 = formatter.parse(firstDate);
        Date date2 = formatter.parse(secondDate);


        if (date2.compareTo(date1) == 0) {
            flag = true;
        } else if (date2.compareTo(date1) < 0) {
            flag = true;
        } else {
            flag = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
try {
    String currentDateString = "5/7/2017";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Date currDate = formatter.parse(currentDateString);

    String pickDateString = "5-7-2017";
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    Date pickDate = formatter.parse(pickDateString);

    if (pickDate.before(currDate)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter the valid Date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```